# How to Filter Content passed to a WordPress Shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

I am using the following custom WordPress `shortcode` to display a list on a page, I am trying to find the 5th LI element and inject a DIV at this point.

```
[expander]
<ul>
    <li>step1</li>
    <li>step 2</li>
    <li>step 3</li>
    <li>step 4</li>
    <li>step 5</li>
    <li>step 6</li>
    <li>step 7</li>
</ul>
[/expander]
```

**Shortcode:**

```
add_shortcode( 'expander', 'my_function' );


function my_function($atts, $content) {

  echo substr_count($content, '<li>'); // 7
  return $content;
}
```

**Intended Output:**

```
<ul>
    <li>step1</li>
    <li>step 2</li>
    <li>step 3</li>
    <li>step 4</li>
    <li>step 5</li>

    <div>
      <li>step 6</li>
      <li>step 7</li>
    </div>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to set this up. The following code will wrap a `<div>` tag around the last two `<li>` tags starting after the 5th element exactly like you requested in your "Intended Output" section of your question, BUT please notice that you could use the `shordcode attributes` to make it dynamic NOT hard-coded by passing the starting and ending numbers as attributes.

The following code is the hard-coded version as you've asked it!

```php
add_shortcode('expander', 'my_function');


function my_function($atts, $content)
{
  $lists_itmes = substr_count($content, '<li>');
  $list_array = explode('<li>', $content); // This will return an array containing of the values between each <li> tag starting from index 1
  $main_content = "";
  for ($i = 0; $i < $lists_itmes + 1; $i++) {
    switch ($i) {
      case 6:
        $main_content .= "<div><li>" . $list_array[6] . "</li>";
        break;
      case 7:
        $main_content .= "<li>" . $list_array[7] . "</li></div>";
        break;
      default:
        $main_content .= "<li>" . $list_array[$i] . "</li></div>";
        break;
    };
  }
  return $main_content;
}
```

And it'll output:

```html
<ul>
    <li>step 1</li>
    <li>step 2</li>
    <li>step 3</li>
    <li>step 4</li>
    <li>step 5</li>

    <div>
      <li>step 6</li>
      <li>step 7</li>
    </div>

</ul>
```